# How do I select rows based on comparisons of different column values across rows after applying groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, group-by

If I have the following data

| Name | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3/4/12 | 7/9/14 |
| B | 5/2/17 | 6/3/18 |
| C | 4/10/13 | 5/12/14 |
| A | 4/6/13 | 7/12/15 |
| B | 4/12/19 | 12/3/21 |
| c | 12/6/13 | 11/3/14 |

For each unique name (A, B, C) I want to select the rows whose end dates fall later than the start date for that same name for every row other than the one whose end date is being considered . So, A and C in this case. Basically, first use groupby (['Name'] and then pick rows where the end date is later than the start date when comparison is made across rows for the same name.

Comment: Can you explain why B is not match? there is always `End` later for each row.

Comment: last number is `year` for both columns? And first is month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both columns to datetimes, so possible compare for less by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and then use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for check if all `True`s per `Name` and last filter indices:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%m/%d/%y')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%m/%d/%y')

s = df['Start'].lt(df['End']).groupby(df['Name']).all()

out = s.index[s].tolist()
print (out)
```

Or change mask for [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and get differencies by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%m/%d/%y')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%m/%d/%y')

out = np.setdiff1d(df['Name'], df.loc[df['Start'].gt(df['End']), 'Name']).tolist()
```